# customizing flex MenuBar or removing the hover effect

Tags: apache-flex, hover, skinning, menubar, customizing

Is there a way to disable the hover effects?
I don't want flex to highlight the entire component for both link buttons and menu bar.

On the menubar, I applied a backgroundSkin, so having flex highlight the whole menubar when the user hovers their mouse on top quitely destroys the design.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great tool for seeing what you can do with CSS in standard components.

http://examples.adobe.com/flex3/consulting/styleexplorer/Flex3StyleExplorer.html#

I looked around and couldn't find a way to easily do what you are asking, you would most likely need to customize the menu bar class to removed that feature.